# display  without repetitions by LINQ-query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sql-server-2008, razor

I have this table:

[image: table]

and I want to display all `friend` names are without repetitions by LINQ.
how do I do it?
Result is:

```
martin
kevin
igor
```

Controler:

```
dbEntities db = new dbEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IQueryable<string> dn = from f in db.table select f.friend;
        IQueryable<string> res = dn.Distinct();
        return View(res);
    }
```

View (ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor):

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.friend)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a combination of `Select` and `Distinct`:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Select(m => m.friend).Distinct()) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Thanx! Its work, but it display nothing and i change @Html.Display(Item) for @Html.ActionLink(item, "...")

Comment: I changed the output from `Display...` to just the friends name (if you don't want to display the name as a link).